# How to trim a a list and generate a numpy 2-D array?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

Say I have a numpy array:

```
[[1,2],
 [3,4],
 [5,6,7]]
```

Is there any compact method to trim the array and make it aligned along the second dimension, i.e.

```
[[1,2],
 [3,4],
 [5,6]]
```

Comment: When you say you have a numpy array `[[1,2],
 [3,4],
 [5,6,7]]`, does it print as `array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7]], dtype=object)`? Numpy doesn't actually support ragged arrays. @SashankGupta's answer would work then (wrapping it in a call to `numpy.array`), though.

Comment: @Dougal thanks, i wasn't sure what to do. Never used numpy but I've heard the arrays had a lot of similar syntax to lists so I thought I'd try answering anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does slicing work for numpy arrays? If so the following code should do the trick.

```
array = [[1,2],
[3,4],
[5,6,7]]

array = numpy.array([a[:2] for a in array])
```

I'm not sure if slicing works for numpy arrays so I will delete this answer if it's wrong.

Comment: I think this is the right answer in this case, because whatever the OP has can't possibly be a 2D numpy array. In general, however, this kind of thing is a bad idea. Numpy indexing, like `a[:,:2]`, is constant-time, with no temporary memory costs and no permanent memory costs; building an array from a listcomp like this is linear time (along one axis), wastes a bunch of temporary memory building lists, and wastes permanent memory copying data instead of viewing it.